# How much self-control does the Green Hulk have?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-incredible-hulk, the-avengers-2012

In the Avengers movie, the Hulk

> shows a fair amount of self-control by the end of the movie (including some amusing set pieces).

I don't recall this being the case in the comics.  Is my memory/Hulk knowledge faulty, or is this a different angle for the movie?

Comment: You've seen the film already?

Comment: Guess *somebody* went to the earliest showings then...

Comment: I'm in Australia, didn't realise it hadn't been realised everywhere else yet. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Hulk's self-control varies wildly throughout the comics.  At times he's a mindless savage, and at times he has the complete personality and intellect of Bruce Banner.  It was revealed at one point that Banner suffers from multiple personality disorder, and the green Hulk is only one of those manifestations.  The original gray Hulk is a separate personality, which appears to have about average intelligence and self-control.

Answer (score 4):

The movie basically implies that

> Banner's 'secret' is that 'he's always angry' (either at himself for his original error in calculation, or just naturally generally pissed off). Either way, it's implied that, certainly by the end of the film, Banner can transform into The Hulk at will. Doesn't explain why he's out of control on the Helicarrier, though - just been suggested to me that, perhaps, this change occurs because he's been prompted by his fall caused by the explosion; I also suggest that the Spear may have had a contributing factor.

Comment: The impression I had was that something was triggered by the caretaker's comment once he had busted through the roof, along the lines of: you aimed to not hit anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you misunderstand the Hulk's motivations.

The Hulk has NEVER intentionally harmed someone he did not perceive as an overt threat, or as intending him a threat. He's not a bully.

Remember that the Hulk is essentially a figment of Bruce Banner's mind. He is like a personality created to protect the main personality, Banner himself. When activated, he will attack until there is no threat whatsoever... but he is still Bruce Banner and is opposed to death like Banner is.

He has no love for property. Clearly. And will destroy anything to get to his threat.

In the movie, they "niced" him up a little bit. Even made him a little playful, which still fits in his definition. But remember that there was a ubiquitous threat (the aliens and Loki) that Bruce Banner knew could not be avoided anywhere, so he stayed to fight. Note that if any of the people he was playful with said they could take him, he would immediately crush them, as they'd become a threat.

The Hulk is actually very self controlled. He's not destruction, just rage. He just happens to cause a lot of destruction.